# Linux cli pipe output of command into another command

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, tooltip

I am using the find command to search for a file. Is there a way to grab the output of the find command and pass that to vim?

```
$ > find . -name *.txt
./file1.txt
./file2.txt
./file3.txt
./file4.txt
```

is there an easy (short) way to

```
vim <some command>
```

to grab file4.txt (or one of the previous files) without typing it out?

I'm looking for a solution similar to the `!!` command in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash builtin command `mapfile` may be what you're looking for. It reads the *lines* of output into an array.

```sh
mapfile -t files < <(find . -name *.txt)
```

The redirection from a process substitution is required to avoid subshells.

Then

- the first file is in `"${files[0]}"`
- the last file is in `"${files[-1]}"`
- all the files are `"${files[@]}"`

Inspect the array with `declare -p files`

Comment: This is the closest to what I'm looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the found files, use command substitution:

```
vim $(find ...) -p
```

If you want to open the output of find, use process substitution:

```
vim <(find ...)
```

Comment: How does this work if the find command returns multiple files?

Comment: In the first case, you can use `:next` to open the next file, and so on.

Comment: Can you provide an example please (I'm very new to cli and linux). Thank you.

Comment: When you run `vim file1 file2 file3`, vim opens `file1`. `:next` or just `:n` is a vim command that opens the next file.

Comment: I think running ```vim $(find ...) -p``` would be a better option in that case, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Ah yes, `-p` sounds better.